# Checked required fields, still getting an error that a required field is missing on Insert

Tags: dml, fields, insert, order

I have the following and get an error on the insert:

```
        Order o1 = new Order(Name ='anOrder', Account = test, Status = 'Activated', EffectiveDate = date.today(), Program__c = clothing.id);
    orders.add(o1);
    insert o1;
```

The exact error is this: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Account Name:You must enter a value: []

The label for the Account is Account Name, the API name is just Account, and there is no other field it could be, with only a couple required fields at all. What might this be? I'm losing my mind over it. I know this is a very general question...will elaborate with whatever else as needed. Should be very simple...

Answer (score 3):

Even though the list of standard fields on `Order` says that the field name is `Account`, the API name of the field with the label `Account Name` on the `Order` object is actually `AccountId`.

This is also true for most, if not all, standard lookup fields.
The API name for a standard lookup to `Opportunity` is `OpportunityId`, to a `Contact` is `ContactId`, etc...

In the web interface, it appears as an account name, but in Apex it is an Id field. Thus, you need to provide the `Id` of your test account, and not the name, when you insert your test order.

```
Account test = new Account(<required fields here>);
insert test;

Order o1 = new Order(
    Name ='anOrder', 
    AccountId = test.Id, 
    Status = 'Activated', 
    EffectiveDate = date.today(), 
    Program__c = clothing.id
);
```

Comment: Related reading: [Create Parent and Child Records in One Insert Call](http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2012/03/create-parent-and-child-records-in-one.html)